# Xamarin Android Sign App with 2 different computers but same keystore

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, keystore, sign

I'm developing a xamarin android application with 2 different computers.. 
one at work and one at home.. 
my first signed version was from my laptop 
then I transfer my keystore file from my laptop to my workplace computer 
everything seems to be fine and I can sign the app from my workplace also but when I want to install it on device I get the error.. as it signed with different keystore..

so I need to sign my app only by my laptop to make it work and install on previous versions

is it logical? is it should be like this? so what about if I want to change my laptop :|

Does anyone have any experience with transferring keystore to another computer?

Comment: I've done this many times.  You should just be able to copy the keystore file from one machine to another.

Comment: @Jason I exactly did copy the keystore to another.. but it's strange why the signed version in my second pc not working with previous versions...

Comment: a keystore can have multiple keys - are you sure you're using the same key on both systems

Comment: what do you mean about multiple keys? I'm just importing the key by exact Alias name with previous one... and same password @Jason

Comment: if you're just doing local testing, you can delete the old version and then install the new one

Comment: If you copy the signing certificate you used on the first machine to the second machine, there will be no problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My mistake was that I tried to copy the keystore file to the second machine (for example D drive)... then import the keystore in visual studio...

I copied the whole keystore folder from

> C:\Users\firstMachine\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore...

to

> C:\Users\secondMachine\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore...

and it's working now

Thanks to guys for comments